# как создать генератор, который достает строки из файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

имеется некий файл - file.txt

```
его содержимое:
[2018-05-14 19:37:47.873687] OK
[2018-05-14 19:38:25.873687] NOK
[2018-05-14 19:38:39.873687] OK
[2018-05-14 19:38:48.873687] NOK
[2018-05-14 19:38:50.873687] NOK
[2018-05-14 19:38:58.873687] NOK
[2018-05-14 19:39:43.873687] OK
[2018-05-14 19:39:46.873687] OK
[2018-05-14 19:39:49.873687] NOK
[2018-05-14 19:40:33.873687] NOK
[2018-05-14 19:41:05.873687] OK
[2018-05-14 19:41:46.873687] OK
[2018-05-14 19:42:29.873687] OK
```

имеется код:

```
def generator():
    nok_dict = {}
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if 'NOK' in line:
                slice = line[1:17]
                if slice in nok_dict:
                    nok_dict[slice] += 1
                else:
                    nok_dict[slice] = 1
```

как из этого кода написать генератор,
который читает файл file.txt и выдает число событий NOK за каждую минуту?
<время> <число повторений>

```
пример:
grouped_events = <создание генератора>
for group_time, event_count in grouped_events:
    print(f'[{group_time}] {event_count}')
```

```
на консоли должно появится что-то вроде

[2018-05-17 01:57] 1234
```

Comment: Мне кажется генератор ему нужен чтобы читать файл не закрывая

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открытие файла лучше не прятать внутрь генератора, а передавать в генератор итерируемый объект (в данном случае файл), из которого генератор формирует обработанные данные.

```
def generator(file):
    prev_time = None
    noc_count = 0

    for line in file:
        if 'NOK' in line:
            time = line[1:17]
            if time != prev_time:
                if prev_time is not None:
                    yield prev_time, noc_count

                prev_time = time
                noc_count = 0

            noc_count += 1

    if noc_count > 0:
        yield prev_time, noc_count


with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for group_time, event_count in generator(file):
        print(f'[{group_time}] {event_count}')
```

На ваших данных результат такой:

```
[2018-05-14 19:38] 4
[2018-05-14 19:39] 1
[2018-05-14 19:40] 1
```

Comment: Где-то читал рекомендацию, что лучше не прятать ввод-вывод (в том числе файловый) где-то глубоко внутри функций, а наоборот оставлять его на поверхности, сейчас уже не помню, что за статья и автор. В данном случае это удобно, например, для тестирования - можно в генератор вместо файла передать список строк, и сравнить полученный результат с требуемым, без необходимости создания файла.

Comment: спасибо за информацию!

Comment: Идеальная задача для `itertools.groupby`.